# Display textbox after selection of option

Tags: forms, radio-button

I'm making a form at the moment and I was wondering how I could get the script to show a textbox after I have selected options "other" or "option 3".

HTML:

```
<select name="choice" onchange="if(this.selectedIndex==5)    
{this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible'}else 
{this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden'};"> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
<option value="1">1</option> 
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option> 
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="other">Other</option> 
</select>

<input type="textbox" name="other" style="visibility:hidden; margin-left:3px"/>
```

Javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('hearabout').addEvent('change', function() { 
if ($('hearabout').value == 'Rekening' ) { 
$('other_input').setStyle('display', 'block'); 
} else { 
$('other_input').setStyle('display', 'none'); 
} 
});

if ($('hearabout').value == 'Rekening' ) { 
$('other_input').setStyle('display', 'block'); 
} else { 
$('other_input').setStyle('display', 'none'); 
} 
});
```

How do I change "this.selectedIndex==5" so that it takes both option 3 and 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add ID for ur select `<select id='someth'>`
2. Add an event for changing the selected value:

`$('#someth').on('change', function(){
      if (('#someth').val() == "other")
           {
                $('#YourInputID').css('display','block');
           }
});`

Dont miss to add `display:none;` in the input style

Comment: Thanks, fixed it now. However, I now have some empty lines in my form from the hidden textboxes. Is it possible to shift the rest down once the textbox is displayed?

Comment: never mind, got it working! my css was overwriting the area in which I was hiding the textboxes

Comment: I recommend using display:none; rather than visibility they are a bit different